# Webapi 2 global exception handling not raised

Tags: c#-4.0, exception, asp.net-web-api2

I'm uising web api 2 to develop services for a client, to manage errors we are using a `ExceptionsFilterAttribute`, but as you know, in this level not all exception are catched.
Some errors are raised in `protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)` and I want to handle them and send a custom message to our client to give him more details about the error, to solve this I create a `GlobalExceptionHandler`

```
  public class GlobalExceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler
{
//A basic DTO to return back to the caller with data about the error
private class ErrorInformation
{
public string Message { get; set; }
public DateTime ErrorDate { get; set; }
}

public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
{

//Return a DTO representing what happened
context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
new ErrorInformation { Message="We apologize but an unexpected error occured. Please try again later.", ErrorDate=DateTime.UtcNow }));

//This is commented out, but could also serve the purpose if you wanted to only return some text directly, rather than JSON that the front end will bind to.
//context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "We apologize but an unexpected error occured. Please try again later."));
}
}
```

In WebApiConfig i added this line :

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());
```

The the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` raise some errors but `GlobalExceptionHandler` is never reached.

Do you have any idea how can I solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application_AuthenticateRequest does not come in the Web API pipeline. So if an exception is thrown in this method those can be caught by the Web API exception handler, because the exception is thrown before the Web API pipeline is started.

There are two ways to do this:

1. Either change the authentication mechanism and use Web API Authentication(IAuthenticationFilter) instead of Application_AuthenticateRequest.

   - If this project has only Web API related controllers, not like MVC and all.
2. Or use Application_Error in the Global.asax.cs file to catch the exception thrown in Application_AuthenticateRequest